# Unsupported Chrome Driver

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

It seems that every time chrome has a new version, I get stuck with this error when running pipeline

```
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98

Current browser version is 97.0.4692.99 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

I've tried install webdriver-manager, it shows the right version, but the problem keeps on. When running locally it all works.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the version of chrome which is installed on the pipeline from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

(then select the agent server version you are using)

Then you need to make sure you are using the same version of the chrome driver in your project.

Or use a self hosted agent instead if you want to use a certain version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade chrome in your release environment to the latest version, 98.0.

If you are running on a windows VM, for example, that means you need to:

1. RDP on to the server
2. load Chrome
3. view the About Chrome page (chrome://settings/help)
4. let it upgrade to the newer version
5. relaunch chrome

Comment: I'm using Pipeline from Azure DevOps, there isn't this kind of access, not that I know.

Comment: @Pablo Did you get a solution for this? I'm having similar issue and searching for a solution.

Comment: @Alka, not exactly. It seems that Azure DevOps take some time to update their Chrome version, but after a while it will work.